# Lower & upper bound on the maximal component given the system of power sums

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, pr.probability, convex-optimization, norms, symmetric-polynomials

Given a non-negative vector $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R_{>0}^n}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$, construct a system of power sum symmetric polynomials (or norms, if you like)
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=a_1,\\
x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2=a_2,\\
\dots\\
x_1^m+x_2^m+\dots+x_n^m=a_m.
\end{cases}
$$
Knowing only the values of $n,a_1,a_2,...,a_m$, what are the bounds on the maximal component $\max\limits_i \{x_i\}$?

For example, in the cases

- $m=1$, we have the sharp bounds $\frac{a_1}{n} \leq \max\limits_i \{x_i\} \leq a_1$.
- $m=2$, using usual optimization methods, we can obtain the sharp upper bound
  $$
  \max\limits_i \{x_i\} \leq \frac{a_1 + \sqrt{(n-1)(na_2-a_1^2)}}{n}
  $$
  and using some geometric arguments, we can obtain the sharp<sup>1</sup> lower bound
  $$
  \frac{a_1 + \sqrt{\frac{(na_2-a_1^2)}{n-1}}}{n} \leq \max\limits_i \{x_i\}.
  $$

#### Questions:

- Is there a closed-form expression for the sharp bounds?
- Are there closed-form expressions for *not necessarily* sharp bounds that improve with higher values of $m$?

#### Motivation

These bounds are useful for [branch and bound algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound). If the $n$ is very large, then simply finding the maximal $x_i$ by iterating through $i$ is not feasible. Yet, in specific problems, the power sums over subsets can be found relatively quickly. Using the obtained bounds, it is possible to remove the subsets from the search space for which the upper bound is smaller than the lower bound of some other subset.

---

<sup>1</sup> A little falsehood. This lower bound is derived without assuming the non-negativity of vector components. In specific cases, a more accurate lower bound can be determined.

Comment: Some notes:
* $m=2$ inequality is known as [Samuelson's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuelson%27s_inequality).
* There doesn't seem to be generalisations of Samuelson's inequality, which uses all the power sums up to $m>3$.
* Related StackExchange questions [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378944/inverting-power-sum-of-symmetric-polynomial), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22850/linear-algebra-of-symmetric-sums).